# How to retrieve the number of video views from another account Instagram

Tags: facebook, instagram

I tested with success this command :

`{ig-user-id}/?fields=business_discovery.username(ig-user-name){media{media_type,caption,timestamp,like_count}}`

I find all the IDs of my media .
Nevertheless for the videos , I would like to have the number of views

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Nevertheless for the videos , I would like to have the number of views

You can't get those for accounts you don't have access to.

Video views are not part of the regular set of `media` fields, they are part of *insights* - and those are only available to the owner of the video, resp. users with admin access to the connected page.